# Gives Error in locale.h

Tags: c++, vector, std

Sorry for the carelessly title, but even I can't identify why the code threw error. I was using vectors in my code, and when I added it like this:

```
std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> vertexArray;
```

Then, it started to give errors like this:

```
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale.h(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'string'
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale.h(28): error C2059: syntax error : 'string'
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale.h(28): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\locale.h(28): error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal list?)
d:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xlocinfo(128): error C3861:  'localeconv': identifier not found
```

How I can fix the error? This error occured when I use std namespace after vector. Sorry I can't decide which header file I should give. I'm giving the header file that vector is in it:

```
#ifndef _MODEL_H
#define _MODEL_H

#include <vector>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <d3dx9.h>

struct CUSTOMVERTEX;

class Model
{
public:
    Model();
    virtual ~Model();

    bool initModel(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device);
    void renderModel(LPDIRECT3DDEVICE9 device);

private:
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 v_buffer;
    LPDIRECT3DINDEXBUFFER9 i_buffer;
    LPDIRECT3DTEXTURE9 tex;
    static const DWORD FVF_FORMAT;
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR3> vertexArray;
    std::vector<D3DXVECTOR2> texcoorArray;
    std::vector<CUSTOMVERTEX> vertices;
    std::vector<short> indices;
};

struct CUSTOMVERTEX
    {
        float x, y, z;
        float tu, tv;
    }

#endif
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error may be caused by the lack of a semicolon at the end of the struct definition.

Try changing:

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    float x, y, z;
    float tu, tv;
}
```

to

```
struct CUSTOMVERTEX
{
    float x, y, z;
    float tu, tv;
}; // added semicolon here
```

At the moment the C compiler will be searching the next included file for a continuation of this code and then reporting an error in the next file.

Comment: It works! I thought the error is about vector or something, I didn't even check the struct...